# Windows 10 Home Edition Environment Variables

Tags: windows-10

I am unable to access my System Environment Variables through the Windows Search bar at the bottom. If I search for 'edit the system environment variables' I get the following error message: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\SytemPropertiesAdvanced.exe - Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.'

When I navigate the file path in Windows Explorer I am able to run this program no problem.

However, if I try searching for 'edit the environment variables for my account' I get the following error message: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe - Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.'

When I navigate to this program in Windows Explorer I notice that the Run Dynamic Link Library file is corrupted. It has no executable file extension '.exe'. I wonder if this is the reason I am unable to open environment variables program using the Search Box?

Comment: You have a spelling mistake: **Sytem**PropertiesAdvanced instead of
**System**PropertiesAdvanced. Is that your mistake in the post, or is that really the message?

Comment: Try [WindowsKey] + [Pause/Break]
Click on "Advanced system settings".. click on [Environment Variables]

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake in the post.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to this from the Microsoft team which returned my Search box items back to normal. I had to run the following command in either PowerShell or the Command Prompt > sfc /scannow.

It then required a system reboot followed by repeating the command > sfc /scannow